# Dataflow fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(Lcom/google/protobuf/Message;)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to get a Dataflow job to run on Google Cloud. It always fails with:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(Lcom/google/protobuf/Message;)Lio/grpc/MethodDescriptor$Marshaller

It's a maven project, here are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
  </dependency>   
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
  </dependency>    
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

I've tried a bunch of different dependency versions. What am I missing?

It has the same result whether I run via exec:java or via a shade jar.

Full stack trace:

> (e8dbd0c1b8b8a22): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(Lcom/google/protobuf/Message;)Lio/grpc/MethodDescriptor$Marshaller;
>   at com.google.iam.v1.IAMPolicyGrpc.(IAMPolicyGrpc.java:56) at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.spi.v1.PublisherSettings$Builder.(PublisherSettings.java:487)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.spi.v1.PublisherSettings$Builder.createDefault(PublisherSettings.java:508)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.spi.v1.PublisherSettings$Builder.access$000(PublisherSettings.java:402)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.spi.v1.PublisherSettings.defaultBuilder(PublisherSettings.java:224)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.spi.DefaultPubSubRpc.(DefaultPubSubRpc.java:138)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.PubSubOptions$DefaultPubSubRpcFactory.create(PubSubOptions.java:60)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.PubSubOptions$DefaultPubSubRpcFactory.create(PubSubOptions.java:54)
>   at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.rpc(ServiceOptions.java:399) at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.PubSubImpl.(PubSubImpl.java:115) at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.PubSubOptions$DefaultPubSubFactory.create(PubSubOptions.java:43)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.pubsub.PubSubOptions$DefaultPubSubFactory.create(PubSubOptions.java:38)
>   at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.service(ServiceOptions.java:391) at
>   com.google.lindsaysmith.titan.DataflowBulkLoadNodes$SendPubSub.sendPubsubMessage(DataflowBulkLoadNodes.java:41)
>   at
>   com.google.lindsaysmith.titan.DataflowBulkLoadNodes$SendPubSub.processElement(DataflowBulkLoadNodes.java:32)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55)
>   at

Comment: What could really help is output from `mvn dependency:tree` if you can share it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793632/grpc-with-dataflow-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer in this situation is that you really must use exactly the version of gRPC and Protocol Buffers declared in the dependencies of the Dataflow SDK. This includes all transitive dependencies, so you may have to suppress gRPC or protobuf dependencies of other libraries so they do not intefere.

You can see the versions [here (gRPC)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/pom.xml#L82) and [here (protobuf)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/pom.xml#L89). I'm leaving them out of this answer so it does not get out of date.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it turns out that actually the issue here was the pubsub library - it references a much newer grpc version that the other two libraries.  Going back to 0.3.0 fixes the NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: Very good point - I've updated my answer slightly to mention that it isn't just if "you" use the library, but if anything in the whole dependency tree does.