# Using Data Flow and Language Service in one project

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using Java and trying to build a simple DataFlow Pipeline that calls Google Cloud Language API to conduct sentiment analysis of a text. There are 2 related dependencies in pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-language</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

At runtime when the code invokes com.google.cloud.language.spi.v1.LanguageServiceClient.create() the following exception happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(Lcom/google/protobuf/Message;)Lio/grpc/MethodDescriptor$Marshaller;
    at com.google.cloud.language.v1.LanguageServiceGrpc.<clinit>(LanguageServiceGrpc.java:41)
```

I read [Dataflow fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(Lcom/google/protobuf/Message;)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40936722/772485) and understand that it has something to do with conflicting dependencies between data flow sdk and language sdk, but I am out of ideas on how to fix it. What can I do to get my code worked?

Comment: Can you post `mvn dependency:tree` results?

Comment: Yeah, I've solved it by using 2.0.0-beta2 version of google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all and compiling/running the project from the command line rather than from Eclipse. The only problem is I can't use Streaming Data Flows anymore