# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller in fabric-java-sdk

Tags: java, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am getting following exception when executing Chain.setmemberServices() in fabric-java-sdk (v0.6.6).

I have checked that grpc version downloaded by gradle is the correct one: 0.15.0

Anything I may be missing?

My dependency in gradle:

```
    'me.reactiv.fabric-java-sdk:fabric-java-sdk:0.6.6'
```

(I've tried the solution of pubsub 0.3.0 explained in [Dataflow fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(Lcom/google/protobuf/Message;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936722/dataflow-fails-with-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-io-grpc-protobuf-protoutils-mar) but won't work)

and the stack trace:

```
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:97)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(Lcom/google/protobuf/Message;)Lio/grpc/MethodDescriptor$Marshaller;
    at org.hyperledger.protos.ECAAGrpc.<clinit>(ECAAGrpc.java:40)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.MemberServicesImpl.<init>(MemberServicesImpl.java:81)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Chain.setMemberServicesUrl(Chain.java:136)
    at com.vetchain.madrid.ChainView.postConstruct(ChainView.java:48)
    ... 62 more
```